# xslt grouping based upon element

Tags: xslt, grouping, xslt-1.0

I have a question about grouping in xml.

1. The first problem is that the xml does not have the structure for grouping lines, the order is OK.
2. Second problem is the fact that the elements for grouping are not repeated if they are the same as in the previous one.

The grouping must be on BodyCustQuotationTrans -detaillines, first level is UnitID, second level is on objectgroupID.

Many thanks if someone could help!

Input xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Report Name="SalesQuotation" Caption="Offerte" Language="EN">
  <Quotation>
    <CustQuotationJour_DeliveryName>Testcustomer</CustQuotationJour_DeliveryName>
    <CustQuotationJour_DeliveryAddress>101 street 3293 CITY</CustQuotationJour_DeliveryAddress>
    <QuotationTxt>Quotation</QuotationTxt>
  </Quotation>
  <Lines>
    <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
      <ItemId>1006055</ItemId>
      <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Laufen Pro kunststof bad 180x80cm WIT ZO</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
      <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
      <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
      <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>511,00</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
      <UnitID>Bathroom</UnitID>
      <UnitNumber>1,00</UnitNumber>
      <ObjectgroupID>Bath</ObjectgroupID>
    </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
    <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
      <ItemId>1036625</ItemId>
      <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Set Laufen badpoten (instelbaar) voor Pr</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
      <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
      <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
      <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>38,00</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
      <UnitID>
      </UnitID>
      <UnitNumber>
      </UnitNumber>
      <ObjectgroupID>
      </ObjectgroupID>
    </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
    <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
      <ItemId>1038952</ItemId>
      <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Chroom badafvoer-overloopkomb.1 ½ met wa</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
      <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
      <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
      <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>56,90</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
      <UnitID>
      </UnitID>
      <UnitNumber>
      </UnitNumber>
      <ObjectgroupID>
      </ObjectgroupID>
    </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
    <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
      <ItemId>1007857</ItemId>
      <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Grohtherm 2000 badthermostaat 15cm chr z</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
      <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
      <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
      <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>353,65</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
      <UnitID>
      </UnitID>
      <UnitNumber>
      </UnitNumber>
      <ObjectgroupID>
      </ObjectgroupID>
    </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
    <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
      <ItemId>2061780</ItemId>
      <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Easy Drain COMPACT 50 1000mm met rooster</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
      <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
      <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
      <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>20,00</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
      <UnitID>
      </UnitID>
      <UnitNumber>1,00</UnitNumber>
      <ObjectgroupID>Shower</ObjectgroupID>
    </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
    <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
      <ItemId>2062352</ItemId>
      <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Easy 2 Seal afdichtingspasta voor o.a. E</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
      <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
      <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
      <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>20,00</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
      <UnitID>
      </UnitID>
      <UnitNumber>
      </UnitNumber>
      <ObjectgroupID>
      </ObjectgroupID>
    </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
    <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
      <ItemId>1007831</ItemId>
      <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Grohtherm 2000 douchethermostaat 15cm ch</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
      <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
      <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
      <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>20,00</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
      <UnitID>
      </UnitID>
      <UnitNumber>
      </UnitNumber>
      <ObjectgroupID>
      </ObjectgroupID>
    </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
    <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
      <ItemId>4044377</ItemId>
      <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Vasco Arabis Bathroomradiator typ HDRM33</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
      <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
      <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
      <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>20,00</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
      <UnitID>
      </UnitID>
      <UnitNumber>1,00</UnitNumber>
      <ObjectgroupID>Radiator</ObjectgroupID>
    </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
    <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
      <ItemId>4044689</ItemId>
      <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Vasco designventielset met thermost.knop</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
      <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
      <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
      <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>20,00</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
      <UnitID>
      </UnitID>
      <UnitNumber>
      </UnitNumber>
      <ObjectgroupID>
      </ObjectgroupID>
    </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
    <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
      <ItemId>1033033</ItemId>
      <CustQuotationTrans_Name>GEBERIT DUOFIX, DE ECHTE!!!</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
      <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
      <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
      <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>20,00</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
      <UnitID>Toiletruim</UnitID>
      <UnitNumber>1,00</UnitNumber>
      <ObjectgroupID>Closet</ObjectgroupID>
    </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
    <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
     <ItemId>1033358</ItemId>
      <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Geberit bedieningsplaat Samba frontbed.</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
      <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
      <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
      <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>20,00</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
      <UnitID>
      </UnitID>
      <UnitNumber>
      </UnitNumber>
      <ObjectgroupID>
      </ObjectgroupID>
    </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
    <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
      <ItemId>1027975</ItemId>
      <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Plaatstalen uitstortgootsteen 51x36 wit</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
      <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
      <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
      <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>20,00</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
      <UnitID>Kitchen</UnitID>
      <UnitNumber>1,00</UnitNumber>
      <ObjectgroupID>Sinc</ObjectgroupID>
    </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
    <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
      <ItemId>1027988</ItemId>
      <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Alape emmerrooster aluminium kleur voor</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
      <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
      <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
      <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>20,00</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
      <UnitID>
      </UnitID>
      <UnitNumber>
      </UnitNumber>
      <ObjectgroupID>
      </ObjectgroupID>
    </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
    <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
      <ItemId>1039264</ItemId>
      <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Syfon universeel 1 1/2"x 40 mm. Mc.alpin</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
      <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
      <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
      <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>9,90</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
      <UnitID_LABEL>Unit ID</UnitID_LABEL>
      <UnitID>
      </UnitID>
      <UnitNumber>
      </UnitNumber>
      <ObjectgroupID>
      </ObjectgroupID>
    </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
  </Lines>
  <Totals>
    <CustQuotationJour_SalesBalance>5.082,19</CustQuotationJour_SalesBalance>
    <CustQuotationJour_EndDisc>0,00</CustQuotationJour_EndDisc>
    <CustQuotationJour_SumMarkup>0,00</CustQuotationJour_SumMarkup>
    <CustQuotationJour_SumTax>1.067,26</CustQuotationJour_SumTax>
    <CustQuotationJour_RoundOff>0,00</CustQuotationJour_RoundOff>
    <CustQuotationJour_QuotationAmount>6.149,45</CustQuotationJour_QuotationAmount>
    <CustQuotationJour_CurrencyCode>EUR</CustQuotationJour_CurrencyCode>
  </Totals>
</Report>
```

The result must be as followed:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Report Name="SalesQuotation" Caption="Offerte" Language="NL">
      <Quotation>
        <CustQuotationJour_DeliveryName>Testcustomer</CustQuotationJour_DeliveryName>
        <CustQuotationJour_DeliveryAddress>101 street 3293 CITY</CustQuotationJour_DeliveryAddress>
        <QuotationTxt>Quotation</QuotationTxt>
      </Quotation>
      <Lines>
          <Unit>
                <UnitID>Bathroom</UnitID>
                <UnitNumber>1,00</UnitNumber>
                  <Objectgroup>
                    <ObjectgroupID>Bath</ObjectgroupID>
                      <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
                        <ItemId>1006055</ItemId>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Laufen Pro kunststof bad 180x80cm WIT ZO</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
                        <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>511,00</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
                      </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
                      <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
                        <ItemId>1036625</ItemId>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Set Laufen badpoten (instelbaar) voor Pr</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
                        <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>38,00</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
                      </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
                      <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
                        <ItemId>1038952</ItemId>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Chroom badafvoer-overloopkomb.1 ½ met wa</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
                        <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>56,90</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
                      </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
                      <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
                        <ItemId>1007857</ItemId>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Grohtherm 2000 badthermostaat 15cm chr z</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
                        <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>353,65</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
                        <UnitID_LABEL>Unit ID</UnitID_LABEL>
                      </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
                    <Subtotalgroup>959,55</Subtotalgroup>
                  </Objectgroup>
                  <Objectgroup>
                    <ObjectgroupID>Shower</ObjectgroupID>
                      <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
                        <ItemId>2061780</ItemId>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Easy Drain COMPACT 50 1000mm met rooster</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
                        <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>20,00</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
                      </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
                      <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
                        <ItemId>2062352</ItemId>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Easy 2 Seal afdichtingspasta voor o.a. E</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
                        <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>20,00</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
                      </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
                      <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
                        <ItemId>1007831</ItemId>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Grohtherm 2000 douchethermostaat 15cm ch</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
                        <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>20,00</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
                      </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
                    <Subtotalgroup>60</Subtotalgroup>
                  </Objectgroup>
                  <Objectgroup>
                    <ObjectgroupID>Radiator</ObjectgroupID>
                      <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
                        <ItemId>4044377</ItemId>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Vasco Arabis Bathroomradiator typ HDRM33</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
                        <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>20,00</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
                      </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
                      <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
                        <ItemId>4044689</ItemId>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Vasco designventielset met thermost.knop</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
                        <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>20,00</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
                      </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
                    <Subtotalgroup>40</Subtotalgroup>
                  </Objectgroup>
                <Subtotalunit>1059,55</Subtotalunit>
          </Unit>
          <Unit>
            <UnitID>Toilet</UnitID>
            <UnitNumber>1,00</UnitNumber>
                   <objectgroup>
                       <ObjectgroupID>Closet</ObjectgroupID>
                        <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
                          <ItemId>1033033</ItemId>
                          <CustQuotationTrans_Name>GEBERIT DUOFIX, DE ECHTE!!!</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
                          <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
                          <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
                          <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>20,00</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
                      </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
                      <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
                        <ItemId>1033358</ItemId>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Geberit bedieningsplaat Samba frontbed.</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
                        <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>20,00</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
                      </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
                    <Subtotalgroup>40</Subtotalgroup>
                 </objectgroup>
                <Subtotalunit>40</Subtotalunit>
          </Unit>
          <Unit>
            <UnitID>Kitchen</UnitID>
            <UnitNumber>1,00</UnitNumber>
              <objectgroup>
                <ObjectgroupID>Sinc</ObjectgroupID>
                      <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
                        <ItemId>1027975</ItemId>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Plaatstalen uitstortgootsteen 51x36 wit</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
                        <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>20,00</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
                      </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
                      <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
                        <ItemId>1027988</ItemId>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Alape emmerrooster aluminium kleur voor</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
                        <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>20,00</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
                      </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
                      <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
                        <ItemId>1039264</ItemId>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Syfon universeel 1 1/2"x 40 mm. Mc.alpin</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
                        <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
                        <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>9,90</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
                      </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
                <Subtotalgroup>49,90</Subtotalgroup>
              </objectgroup>
            <Subtotalunit>49,90</Subtotalunit>
          </Unit>
  </Lines>
  <Totals>
    <CustQuotationJour_SalesBalance>5.082,19</CustQuotationJour_SalesBalance>
    <CustQuotationJour_EndDisc>0,00</CustQuotationJour_EndDisc>
    <CustQuotationJour_SumMarkup>0,00</CustQuotationJour_SumMarkup>
    <CustQuotationJour_SumTax>1.067,26</CustQuotationJour_SumTax>
    <CustQuotationJour_RoundOff>0,00</CustQuotationJour_RoundOff>
    <CustQuotationJour_QuotationAmount>6.149,45</CustQuotationJour_QuotationAmount>
    <CustQuotationJour_CurrencyCode>EUR</CustQuotationJour_CurrencyCode>
  </Totals>
</Report>
```

Comment: For questions about grouping in XSLT, the answer depends entirely on whether you are using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. Since both are in widespread use, you need to say.

Comment: In that case you've got your work cut out. I don't do XSLT 1.0 questions (too much like hard work), but look up "Muenchian grouping" in your favourite XSLT 1.0 text book and you'll find an explanation of how to approach it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are grouping by 'sequential' elements, so the elements in the group immediately follow the element they are grouped with. In your case, you are grouping elements by **UnitID** and then within this by **ObjectgroupID**. Because of this you will need to define two keys

```
<xsl:key 
  name="Unit" 
  match="BodyCustQuotationTrans[UnitID = '']" 
  use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::BodyCustQuotationTrans[UnitID != ''][1])" />
<xsl:key 
  name="Objectgroup" 
  match="BodyCustQuotationTrans[ObjectgroupID = '']" 
  use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::BodyCustQuotationTrans[ObjectgroupID != ''][1])" />
```

The first key groups elements by the first most preceding element with a **UnitID** set. The second groups elements by the first most preceding element with an **Objectgroup** set.

Firstly, you would get the elements with a **UnitID** set, like so (The mode here is used because there will be multiple templates matching **BodyCustQuotationTrans**

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="BodyCustQuotationTrans[UnitID != '']" mode="Unit" />
```

Within this template you need to then get the sub-groups, in this case this will the elements within the Unit group which have **ObjectgroupID** set

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="self::*|key('Unit', generate-id())[ObjectgroupID != '']" mode="Objectgroup" />
```

Finally, within the template that matches this, you can just get the elements within the group using the **Objectgroup** key

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="self::*|key('Objectgroup', generate-id())" />
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="Unit" match="BodyCustQuotationTrans[UnitID = '']" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::BodyCustQuotationTrans[UnitID != ''][1])" />
   <xsl:key name="Objectgroup" match="BodyCustQuotationTrans[ObjectgroupID = '']" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::BodyCustQuotationTrans[ObjectgroupID != ''][1])" />

   <xsl:template match="Lines">
      <Lines>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="BodyCustQuotationTrans[UnitID != '']" mode="Unit" />
      </Lines>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="BodyCustQuotationTrans" mode="Unit">
      <Unit>
         <xsl:copy-of select="UnitID|UnitNumber" />
         <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*|key('Unit', generate-id())[ObjectgroupID != '']" mode="Objectgroup" />
         <subtotalunit><xsl:value-of select="sum(CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice|key('Unit', generate-id())/CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice)" /></subtotalunit>
      </Unit>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="BodyCustQuotationTrans" mode="Objectgroup">
      <Objectgroup>
         <xsl:copy-of select="ObjectgroupID" />
         <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*|key('Objectgroup', generate-id())" />
         <subtotalgroup><xsl:value-of select="sum(CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice|key('Objectgroup', generate-id())/CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice)" /></subtotalgroup>
      </Objectgroup>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="BodyCustQuotationTrans/UnitID|BodyCustQuotationTrans/UnitNumber|BodyCustQuotationTrans/ObjectgroupID" />

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
<Report Name="SalesQuotation" Caption="Offerte" Language="EN">
   <Quotation>
      <CustQuotationJour_DeliveryName>Testcustomer</CustQuotationJour_DeliveryName>
      <CustQuotationJour_DeliveryAddress>101 street 3293 CITY</CustQuotationJour_DeliveryAddress>
      <QuotationTxt>Quotation</QuotationTxt>
   </Quotation>
   <Lines>
      <Unit>
         <UnitID>Bathroom</UnitID>
         <UnitNumber>1,00</UnitNumber>
         <Objectgroup>
            <ObjectgroupID>Bath</ObjectgroupID>
            <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
               <ItemId>1006055</ItemId>
               <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Laufen Pro kunststof bad 180x80cm WIT ZO</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
               <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
               <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
               <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>511,00</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
            </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
            <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
               <ItemId>1036625</ItemId>
               <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Set Laufen badpoten (instelbaar) voor Pr</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
               <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
               <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
               <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>38,00</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
            </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
            <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
               <ItemId>1038952</ItemId>
               <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Chroom badafvoer-overloopkomb.1 ½ met wa</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
               <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
               <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
               <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>56,90</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
            </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
            <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
               <ItemId>1007857</ItemId>
               <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Grohtherm 2000 badthermostaat 15cm chr z</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
               <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
               <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
               <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>353,65</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
            </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
            <subtotalgroup>959,55</subtotalgroup>
         </Objectgroup>
         <Objectgroup>
            <ObjectgroupID>Shower</ObjectgroupID>
            <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
               <ItemId>2061780</ItemId>
               <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Easy Drain COMPACT 50 1000mm met rooster</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
               <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
               <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
               <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>20,00</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
            </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
            <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
               <ItemId>2062352</ItemId>
               <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Easy 2 Seal afdichtingspasta voor o.a. E</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
               <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
               <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
               <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>20,00</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
            </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
            <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
               <ItemId>1007831</ItemId>
               <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Grohtherm 2000 douchethermostaat 15cm ch</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
               <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
               <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
               <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>20,00</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
            </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
            <subtotalgroup>60</subtotalgroup>
         </Objectgroup>
         <Objectgroup>
            <ObjectgroupID>Radiator</ObjectgroupID>
            <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
               <ItemId>4044377</ItemId>
               <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Vasco Arabis Bathroomradiator typ HDRM33</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
               <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
               <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
               <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>20,00</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
            </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
            <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
               <ItemId>4044689</ItemId>
               <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Vasco designventielset met thermost.knop</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
               <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
               <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
               <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>20,00</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
            </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
            <subtotalgroup>40</subtotalgroup>
         </Objectgroup>
         <subtotalunit>1059,55</subtotalunit>
      </Unit>
      <Unit>
         <UnitID>Toiletruim</UnitID>
         <UnitNumber>1,00</UnitNumber>
         <Objectgroup>
            <ObjectgroupID>Closet</ObjectgroupID>
            <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
               <ItemId>1033033</ItemId>
               <CustQuotationTrans_Name>GEBERIT DUOFIX, DE ECHTE!!!</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
               <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
               <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
               <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>20,00</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
            </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
            <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
               <ItemId>1033358</ItemId>
               <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Geberit bedieningsplaat Samba frontbed.</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
               <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
               <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
               <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>20,00</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
            </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
            <subtotalgroup>40</subtotalgroup>
         </Objectgroup>
         <subtotalunit>40</subtotalunit>
      </Unit>
      <Unit>
         <UnitID>Kitchen</UnitID>
         <UnitNumber>1,00</UnitNumber>
         <Objectgroup>
            <ObjectgroupID>Sinc</ObjectgroupID>
            <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
               <ItemId>1027975</ItemId>
               <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Plaatstalen uitstortgootsteen 51x36 wit</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
               <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
               <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
               <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>20,00</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
            </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
            <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
               <ItemId>1027988</ItemId>
               <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Alape emmerrooster aluminium kleur voor</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
               <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
               <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
               <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>20,00</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
            </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
            <BodyCustQuotationTrans>
               <ItemId>1039264</ItemId>
               <CustQuotationTrans_Name>Syfon universeel 1 1/2"x 40 mm. Mc.alpin</CustQuotationTrans_Name>
               <CustQuotationTrans_Qty>1,00</CustQuotationTrans_Qty>
               <salesUnitTxt>ST</salesUnitTxt>
               <CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>9,90</CustQuotationTrans_SalesPrice>
               <UnitID_LABEL>Unit ID</UnitID_LABEL>
            </BodyCustQuotationTrans>
            <subtotalgroup>49,9</subtotalgroup>
         </Objectgroup>
         <subtotalunit>49,9</subtotalunit>
      </Unit>
   </Lines>
   <Totals>
      <CustQuotationJour_SalesBalance>5.082,19</CustQuotationJour_SalesBalance>
      <CustQuotationJour_EndDisc>0,00</CustQuotationJour_EndDisc>
      <CustQuotationJour_SumMarkup>0,00</CustQuotationJour_SumMarkup>
      <CustQuotationJour_SumTax>1.067,26</CustQuotationJour_SumTax>
      <CustQuotationJour_RoundOff>0,00</CustQuotationJour_RoundOff>
      <CustQuotationJour_QuotationAmount>6.149,45</CustQuotationJour_QuotationAmount>
      <CustQuotationJour_CurrencyCode>EUR</CustQuotationJour_CurrencyCode>
   </Totals>
</Report>
```

Comment: >Hi Tim, thanks for the solution. I am going to test it on the  files from Dynamics AX.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for a great solution! I had to add a line to remove the spaces in the key elements: <xsl:strip-space elements="UnitID ObjectGroupID" />. There is a problem with the sum, on my files the result is NAN, the files are in Dutch format (511,00), so the decimal sign is "," and not "."

Comment: Ah yes. When I tested, I manually switched the commas and full stops to get it to work on my British PC. Doing sums on numbers from different locales is probably a wholenew question!